# How to duplicate post on selected subsites on Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: wordpress, publish, multisite

I have Wordpress Multisite Network with somes subsites. I want to be able to duplicate or link post to selected subsites at the publish/edit page of the post. Something like the categories widget.

How may I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here another solution, this one is free.

[Broadcast WordPress Plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that this plugin is doing what you are looking for.

[simple-multisite-crossposting](https://rudrastyh.com/plugins/simple-multisite-crossposting)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try these types of plugins [WordPress Multisite Content Copier/Updater](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-content-copier/)

Comment: Interesting. But it's nearly what I wanted to. That plugin go bulk copy. I prefer the other two solutions proposed by @Geemeethe Theway